# Billing my clients in different currencies, does it matter?

Tags: banking, foreign-currency

I have a Canadian LLC (with a Canadian dollars bank account) and recently got my first offshore client from Singapore.

In our signed contract my rate is in Canadian dollars, and then my client asked me in which currency I will send my first invoice (CAD or SGD), which made me confused.

I have the option to send an invoice of 1000 CAD or ~1023 SGD (on today's exchange rate). The payment will be made in Wire

Does it matter for any of us? Would he pay more fees to send CAD, or would I pay to receive SGD?

Thank you.

Comment: How much either of you might pay in fees will vary by the method used, and is likely to change all the time. If the _contract_ specifies a rate in CAD then my _suspicion_ is that it's the client's obligation to get you that many CADs, and that you should invoice them that many CADs. If you _allow_ them to pay that CAD invoice by sending you SGD, that's another matter, but if what you receive only ends up as 950 CAD after conversion, I would expect they would still owe you 50 CAD (because the invoice was for 1000).

Comment: However, if you invoiced them in SGD at today's rate, and by the time they paid and the money got to you the rate had changed and you only got 950 CAD, I _expect_ you'd be out of luck, since they've paid what you asked of them. However, I don't know for certain, hence not an answer.

Comment: It makes sense, thanks @TripeHound, I was advised today to bill always in my local currency, so the currency exchange rate markup charged by banks will be on the client side.